# Number theoretic characterisation of cosine?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, trigonometry

Let $f:[0, \pi/2]: \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an infinitely differentiable function, with $f(0)=1, f(\pi/2)=0$, such that $f(\pi \mathbb{Q}) \cap \mathbb{Q} = \{0,1/2,1\}$.

Classical results show that the cosine function satisfies these properties. Is it unique in this regard?

I doubt it's the only such function, but I was unable to write down any other or come up with an argument proving the existence of others. Apologies if this turns out to be elementary, I couldn't find anything online about this.

Comment: $\cos3x$ (more generally, $\cos kx$ for any odd integer $k$) satisfies the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other distinct such functions are $$f_s(x)=sx(x- \pi /2)(x- \pi /6)+ \cos x$$ where $s \neq 0$ is any algebraic number ($f_0$ is just $\cos$).

Indeed, for all $r \in \Bbb{Q} \cap [0, 1/2]$ you have
$$f_s(\pi r ) = s\pi^3 r(r-1/2)(r-1/3) + \cos ( \pi r) = \mbox{transcendental} + \mbox{algebraic}$$
is a transcendental number unless $r \in \{ 0, 1/2, 1/3 \}$.

Comment: (+1), but $g(x)$ should have $\pi^{3}$ on the right side...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks, edited!

Comment: Great, nice example.